# how can i change background pattern image on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, arrays

I have tried many scripts to change background image on page refresh but i cant find any proper solution as i required.

Here is my html code.

```
<div  class="under_header" 

             style="height:600px;
             margin-top:0px; 
             background:url(images/pattern.png),
             url(images/latest_movie/movie_image.jpg)center 76px fixed no-repeat; 
            -moz-background-size:auto, cover; background-size:auto, cover; 

              box-shadow: inset 945px 0px 645px -645px black, inset -945px 0px 645px -645px black;">                                

</div>
```

In that i want to change background patterns on page refresh like pattern.png, pattern1.png, pattern2.png. at `backgroud:url(images/pattern.png)`.

Comment: Does it have to be consecutive? Or random also works for you?

Comment: Do you want it to load in a particular order?

Comment: That can be any images randomly.

Comment: NO not in order, image name does not matter. it can be any images randomly  @surajck

Comment: Is it possible for you to use jQuery?

Comment: The duplicate question linked to this has nothing to do with this question ..
To answer this, use PHP, hold your images URL in an array like `$images = array('bg.jpg', 'bg.jpg');` then use [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to get a random index from `$images` array. Then call that random index from `$images` like this (CSS); `background-image: url(<?php print $images[array_rand($images)]; ?>)`

Comment: @sinaza yeah its just static that i want to use other images on page refresh. so whether i use jQuery or javascript  both will work.